# How to find tools that are presented in the papers?

Tags: publications, software, engineering, tools

I just searched a couple of papers related to the subject that I'm trying to work on. And the thing is that they all presented a tool that helped them do the job.

Here some of them:
[mapo](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAufnFldDQAhWCWBQKHf56AqIQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.92.7014%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNFHFVo9n0RM1oqD5TySCrYlxWO2hw&sig2=mheED1q1t9vMxuht3EEICg),
[mica](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1698785/),
any many more.

I am trying to get to know these tools to see what is it that they are good at or bad at, but I searched and I couldn't find them!

Is it all the tools that I can't find? Is it about all the papers that the tools that they make are not on the Internet?
If they are how am I suppose to find them?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what all you're asking in your final paragraph, but have you tried contacting the authors of the paper to find out how you might get access to the tools?

Comment: @Ian_Fin nope, but now i have a clue that i must contact the authors, tnq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tools you state are prototypes developed by the authors. They may not always have enough rank to be easily Googled, so the best place to search for them would be the respective institution sites and author sites.

For instance,

- MAPO can be found in the corresponding author [Tao Xie's website](http://taoxie.cs.illinois.edu/software.html) (although you might need his consent to access it).
- MICA is available [in GitHub](https://github.com/efficient/mica) with copyright by Carnegie Mellon University.

If that doesn't work, the best thing to do would be to mail the corresponding author requesting the required access to the software.

Comment: This is a great help, tnq

Comment: Also, in a more general case, if those would not be personal tools of the authors, they should have cited relevant papers which give you information on where to get the tools.